# Raspberry Pi 3 B - no ping from Windows Computer on LAN

Tags: pi-3, ssh, windows, ping

i have a bit of a connection issue between my newly acquired rpi 3B and my PC.
Currently im going on 16h+ spent trying to debug the issue with no success and im turning to the community in hopes of fresh ideas :)

What i would like to do is open a ssh connection PC->rpi, where both are connected to LAN.
PC is running win8.1 and is connected to LAN.

Behaviour.

1. default config on Wifi - fresh install

   - pulling correct IP from router (192.168.1.4/24)
   - router to/from rpi successful ping
   - rpi has internet access
   - local pc to from rpi cannot ping

I have discovered, that my router has AP isolation enabled, but since it has proprietary sw from my ISP, i cannot change this. I enabled UPnP though, nothing changed.

So i resorted to try both PC and rpi connected to the LAN ports of the router:

2. default on LAN - fresh install

   - rpi is pulling an IP: 169.254.16.3(/16). Mind you this should not be correct, router is configured to give IPs from 192.168.1.xx-254
   - router to/from rpi failed ping
   - pc to/from rpi failed ping
   - rpi has no internet

Moving on:

3. - sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces  -> as original (empty)
   - sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf: (added below)

     - interface eth0
     - static ip_address = 192.168.1.10/24
     - static routers = 192.168.1.1
     - static domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1

Result =>

- rpi is getting static correct IP as above
- rpi cannot connect to internet / no ping to google.com
- router to/from rpi successful ping
- pc to/from rpi failed ping

Ive tried a bunch more other things (one of them changing the default 22 port to 55555) but no luck with anything and i feel my sanity slipping.

In the end im not able to get a ping from pc-rpi, if you have any thoughts on this please let me know.
Did not try PC connected to wifi yet, will do it in the meantime but i would like to avoid this solution, at least for the long term..

Happy holidays : )

Edit: SSH works on wifi :(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70868/discussion-on-question-by-6l6o6st-raspberry-pi-3-b-no-ping-from-windows-comput). Hello and welcome @6l6o6st, please make sure to edit all additional info (as requested by comments) directly into the question itself. Thanks.