# Unable to Ping to / from PC to Pi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3, ping

I have similar issue as mentioned 
 in below link 
[Raspberry Pi 3 B - no ping from Windows Computer on LAN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76915/raspberry-pi-3b-b-no-ping-from-windows-computer-on-lan?newreg=a50d565df87748faa45343e55a57868e)

The pi model is 3B+ and have installed latest NOOBS from the below
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest

Pi has internet connection and shows the proper LAN ip address ( 192.168.0.106 ) , PC is also on the same network (192.168.0.104 ), but neither of them ping with each other. 
SSH through Putty  does not work. 
Am at my wit's end trying to solve this issue. Any suggestions will be of immense help

regards,
Saagar

Comment: Can any of them ping the default gateway?

Comment: NOOBS is not an operating system. It is an installer for Raspbian and more. What operating system do you install with NOOBS? Do you use Raspbian Stretch? Please execute these commands, edit your question and paste its output to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is the SSH service enabled on your Pi?
   You can check this by running `sudo systemctl status ssh`. If it isn't, then do the following.  ([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/))

   - Enter `sudo raspi-config` in a terminal window
   - Select Interfacing Options
   - Navigate to and select `SSH`
   - Choose `Yes`
   - Select `Ok`
   - Choose `Finish`
2. If it is indeed running, but you still are unable to connect to it, then, as mentioned in the link you provided, does your SSH work on WiFi instead of a wired connection?

   - If it does, then did you previously assign your eth0 connection a static IP instead of your wlan0? If you did, then follow [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=192963) tutorial as to how to reverse this.